# How to create a database with collation value from other database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am taking a backup of database and restoring it on other system which have other collation. Want to know how can I get the collation from database of target system and use it to create new database with this collation instead of collation set in backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify collation while restoring..Only options are

1.Alter collation once restore is done
2.IF you have scripted out the database,then you can alter the scripts

to get collation :

```
select name, collation_name from sys.databases
```

To alter collation:

```
USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE dbname
COLLATE collationneeded ;  
GO
```

Comment: After restoring the database how can I get collation of existing database and set it for restored one?

Comment: Otherwise, More specifically, How can to set database collation to default collation. For example I can use:

Comment: ALTER DATABASE dbname COLLATE Japanese_CI_AI. But is there any way I can use some variable or somehow set collation to default collation instead of giving a specific collation name( like Japanese_CI_AI).